# How do I search Contact Source?

Tags: custom-search

I am getting people added to our database from Contact Source called Get Updates.  I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Search > Search Builder and do this:

[image]

I can't comment on if this is the best way to do this, or perhaps have them added to a Group called 'Get Updates' instead so it becomes a discrete search for all those records, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Friendship Circle, Welcome to SE.

There are many ways the contact may have contact source.

1. Contacts being created from import with contact source.
2. Webform/Caldera for submissions with contact source set as default and hidden
3. Schedule job that pulls contact from external source and add's into CiviCRM like google contact sync, mailchimp sync etc
4. Contribute/Custom modules/plugin that is responsible to add contacts from a form like newsletter signup etc

Pradeep